# A smaller value for a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Specifically, I want to prove that the sequence $\{Q_{n}\}$ defined by

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
Q_{1}=x_{1}\\ 
Q_{n+1}=Q_{n}+x_{n+1}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}

from where $\{x_{n}\}$ is defined by

\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{1}=\frac{1}{3}\\ 
x_{n+1}=1-\sqrt[3]{1-x_{n}}
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation*}

is a Cauchy sequence,then I want to prove that it is convergent, namely, that it is bounded and increasing.

I have already proved that it is growing, so let's see by induction.

For the base step it is clear that $Q_{1}=\frac{1}{3} \leq Q_{2}=\frac{1}{3}+1-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{1}{3}}$.

For the inductive step note that $Q_{n+2}=Q_{n+1}+1-\sqrt[3]{1-x_{n+1}}$ and you have to $x_{n+1}\in (0, 1)$ whereby $1-\sqrt[3]{1-x_{n+1}} > 0$ and thus $Q_{n+2}=Q_{n+1}+1-\sqrt[3]{1-x_{n+1}}\geq Q_{n+1}$.

Now, let's try to prove that it is bounded. It appears to be bounded by 2, this can also be verified by induction.

For the base step it is clear that $|Q_{1}|=\frac{1}{3} \leq 2 $

For the inductive step $|Q_{n+1}|=|Q_{n}+x_{n+1}|\leq |Q_{n}|+|x_{n+1}| \leq 1+|x_{n+1}| \leq 2$ because $x_{n+1} \ (0, 1)$

it seems to work, but there is a dimension smaller than $2$? any suggestions? thanks for the help!

Comment: Q seems to approach a number around .526 by computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696642/prove-that-a-sequence-q-n-is-a-cauchy-sequence), one has
$$x_n = 1-\left(\dfrac{2}{3} \right)^\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} $$

In particular, using that $1-e^x \leq -x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, one gets $$ x_n \leq \dfrac{1}{3^{n-1}} \ln \left( \dfrac{3}{2}\right)$$

Since $\displaystyle Q_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_n $, you deduce that
$$Q_n \leq \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{3^{k-1}} \ln \left( \dfrac{3}{2}\right)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{3^{k-1}} \ln \left( \dfrac{3}{2}\right) = \dfrac{3}{2} \ln \left( \dfrac{3}{2}\right) \simeq 0.608...
$$

---

**Edit :** one can get better bounds with the following method. One has
$$x_n = 1-\left(\dfrac{2}{3} \right)^\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} = - \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\ln^k\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)}{3^{k(n-1)}k!}$$

Let $Q = \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} Q_n$ : one has
$$Q = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} x_n  = -\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}   \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{\ln^k\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)}{3^{k(n-1)}k!}= -   \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{\ln^k\left(\frac{2}{3} \right)}{3^{k(n-1)}k!} = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\left(3\ln\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)\right)^k}{k!(3^k-1)}$$

This is an alternating series whose first term is positive, hence for every $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$, one has
$$\boxed{Q \leq \sum_{k=1}^{2N-1} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\left(3\ln\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)\right)^k}{k!(3^k-1)}}$$

For $N=1$, this gives the estimate above ;

For $N=2$, this gives $\displaystyle Q \leq \sum_{k=1}^{3} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\left(3\ln\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)\right)^k}{k!(3^k-1)} \simeq 0.52726...$ ;

For $N=3$, this gives $\displaystyle Q \leq \sum_{k=1}^{5} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\left(3\ln\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)\right)^k}{k!(3^k-1)} \simeq 0.52621...$ ;

For $N=4$, this gives $\displaystyle Q \leq \sum_{k=1}^{7} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\left(3\ln\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)\right)^k}{k!(3^k-1)} \simeq 0.52620...$ ;

and so on : increasing $N$, you get more and more precise bounds.

Comment: $x_n=1-(2/3)^{1/3^{n-1}}$, then your estimate should be 3 times greater

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Corrected, thanks.